# Disable cmd.exe resizing

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, console

Is it possible to make the command prompt (cmd.exe) on Windows non-resizable?

I've specified buffer size (ScreenBuffSize) in the HKCU\Console registry, but I can click and drag the border of the window to make it smaller (just not bigger). I would like to disable resizing at all.

Comment: Just for your own account, or for multiple accounts on the computer(s)?

Comment: @music2myear My own account

Comment: Do you want to disable resizing ONLY for the command window, or for other windows as well?

Comment: What is the reason? Did you want to avoid accidental mouse drags or something else? Do you consider third party terminals as an option?

Comment: @music2myear Only the command terminal I have set up in the `HKCU\Console`. I initiate it by calling `start "MyCMD" %COMSPEC% /k`. I would like to set a key or something that disables and resizing of the window.

Comment: @Maximus Just a preference for some application display sugar. I wont have access to 3rd party terminals. I set the screen buffer size and dont want the window to be any larger or smaller than that.

Comment: Will you be able to use third-party apps besides terminal clients?

Comment: Without 3rd party terminals you can't get size restriction.

Comment: @Maximus Do you know of a terminal that can be packaged with an application so that it only resides with the application? That way I wouldn't have to rely on the native OS CLI.

Comment: I'm the author of ConEmu